# Cassandra (DSE): Services or No-Services, what to prefer?

Tags: cassandra

Using DSE Cassandra, what is the tradeoff between services and no-services startups? Does it make any difference in terms of features / limitations / ease of operations? What is usually preferred?

Comment: can you elaborate your question little more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services/no-services makes absolutely no difference in terms of features or ease of operations after the installation is finished. The GUI services/no-services installer was introduced recently (DataStax 4.5) to simplify installation and configuration for folks who are not comfortable with command line tools. In earlier releases, before the GUI installer was introduced, you could install DSE on Ubuntu or RHEL and run DataStax Enterprise as a service (background process/daemon). I think the advantage of running something as a service is that the service gets priority and resources over non-services. I think most DataStax Enterprise users on Ubuntu and RHEL run DataStax Enterprise as a service.

On Ubuntu, I think the DataStax GUI installer is using apt under the covers, and on RHEL, yum. The DataStax GUI installer puts files in different directories than the tarball installer on some platforms. Some directory locations used by the GUI installer on some platforms changed from the 4.5.0 release to 4.5.x release.

Generally, command line tools are more reliable than GUIs, but that might not be true for the DataStax GUI installer. GUIs add a layer of complexity that sometimes causes problems. Experienced users prefer command line tools.